# LibreTranslate deploy time exceed problem

Tags: python, deployment, netlify, translate

Im trying to deploy instance of LibreTranslate python serverless. In netlify I exceed the build time, because it downloads 80+ languages. Any ideas how to install only 3 languages or any other library?

In netlify I exceed the build time, because it downloads 80+ languages.

Comment: [RTFM](https://github.com/LibreTranslate/LibreTranslate?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert on translation libraries including that one so can't give you direct advice.  However, the indirect advice which you'd probably get from the Netlify Support team or forums as well, is to not install them at build time at all.  You could:

- do the normal installation in your local copy of the source tree
- then, remove the 77+ languages you don't need from that installation
- next, commit the remainder of the files to your repo
- so that you can use them immediately without installing anything at build time, as they'll be fetched with the clone.

In case some of the files are massive and this causes a slowdown with the checkout of your repo (unlikely but all things are possible), you could additionally activate git LFS to make the checkout smoother.  Do not, however, use Large Media (which is based on LFS) since it is nearing the end of its life as a supported product and has a lot of gotchas, but plain LFS should work fine (how?  see the variables described in the section just **above** this section of the docs to activate and potentially include non-standard extensions in 'what will be fetched via LFS':  https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/#read-only-variables)